# Leaflet: how to use a custom marker on a geojson layer?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to put on a Leaflet map a geojson and all works fine until I use the default blu marker.

Now I'd like to use a custom marker (a little .png icon) and I've changed my code in the follow

```
 var my_json;
 $.getJSON('../Dati/my-geojson.geojson', function(data) {
           my_json = L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                var smallIcon = L.Icon({
                    options: {
                        iconSize: [27, 27],
                        iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                        popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
                        iconUrl: 'icone/chapel-2.png'
                    }
                });
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
            },
           onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                   layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.ATT1 + '<br />'
                                                 + feature.properties.ATT2);
           }
         });
 my_json.addTo(markers.addTo(map));
 TOC.addOverlay(my_json, "My layer name in TOC");
 map.removeLayer(my_json); 
 });
```

the error that I can see in Firebug is

```
TypeError: this.options.icon is undefined
var anchor = L.point(this.options.icon.options.popupAnchor || [0, 0]);
```

something is going wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 11):

Just change

```
 var smallIcon = L.Icon({
   options: {
     iconSize: [27, 27],
     iconAnchor: [13, 27],
     popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
     iconUrl: 'icone/chapel-2.png'
   }
 });
```

to

```
 var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
     iconSize: [27, 27],
     iconAnchor: [13, 27],
     popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
     iconUrl: 'icone/chapel-2.png'
 });
```

or

```
 var smallIcon = L.icon({
     iconSize: [27, 27],
     iconAnchor: [13, 27],
     popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
     iconUrl: 'icone/chapel-2.png'
 });
```

See the [icon official documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon) and [this tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html).

You do not use `new` for L.Icon (It's supposed to not be required but without it, we encountered an issue...)

See [a demo](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/61fa02b35abf4b971390) reusing your sample.

Your syntax should be working when extending `L.Icon` class.

Comment: Thanks ThomasG77 for the reply. I've tried you suggestion but something still does not work. Firebug still tells to me ... "TypeError: this.options.icon is undefined
var anchor = L.point(this.options.icon.options.popupAnchor || [0, 0]);".

Comment: `L.Icon` should be `new L.Icon`

Comment: Neither the doc nor the tutorial use "new".  I believe it's optional.

Comment: You are right in theory but copy [my sample demo code](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/61fa02b35abf4b971390) and remove `new` without it... I do not have an explanation here :(

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me if I'm wrong since I'm sorta new to this, but I noticed that you spelled it as **L.Icon** with a capital **I**. Maybe the version is newer or something but it doesn't work when i spell it that way. **L.icon** with a small **i** works fine for me.

You also used the small case name in the return statement.